# Graph::printAllPaths

Tags: c++, excel, text, graph

A code which is written in C++  writes a sequence of numbers in the output console.In fact, this code tries to enumerate all path in a graph between a source and a destination node. for example a single run generates:

1,2,3

4,5

6,7

The whole code can be find in here:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-paths-given-source-destination/

What I am trying to do is write these numbers in a text or excel file . I am completely new to C++ so I really appreciate your help on what changes should I do in order to export the output in excel or text file.

Let's say the main code is :

```
// Driver program
int main()
{
    // Create a graph given in the above diagram
    Graph g(4);
    g.addEdge(0, 1);
    g.addEdge(0, 2);
    g.addEdge(0, 3);
    g.addEdge(2, 0);
    g.addEdge(2, 1);
    g.addEdge(1, 3);
    int s = 2, d = 3;
    g.printAllPaths(s, d);

    return 0;
}
```

we already defined `g.printAllPaths` and  `g.addEdge`.

What I am trying to do is generate a text file and write the output in there:

```
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("sample.txt");
outFile <<g.printAllPaths(s, d)<<endl;
outFile.close();
```

but this does not work.

Comment: "This doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. "Hello, Tom's auto repair? My car doesn't work, can it be fixed?"

Comment: What does the Graph.printAllPaths return? a const char& or what?

Comment: Edit your post with the code for `Graph::printAllPaths`.

Comment: This code tries to find all possible path from a source node to a destination node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a function with the `operator<<`, you will need to have it return the stream:

```
std::ostream& printAllPaths(std::ostream& outfile, int s, int d)
{
  // Output to the stream,
  // Example:
  outfile << s << ", " << d;
  return outfile;
}
```

An alternative is to not chain the function with the `operator<<`:

```
void Graph::printAllPaths(std::stream& outfile, int s, int d)
{
  outfile << s << ", " << d;
}

// Usage
std::ofstream outfile("sample.txt");
if (outfile)
{
  g.printAllPaths(outfile, s, d);
  outfile << "endl";
  outfile.close();
}
```